# How does validation work in case of a browser cache, proxy cache and an origin server?

Tags: validation, browser-cache, etag, http-caching, http-status-code-304

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching#Freshness

> when the cache receives a request for a stale resource, it forwards this request with a If-None-Match to check if it is in fact still fresh. If so, the server returns a 304 (Not Modified) header without sending the body of the requested resource, saving some bandwidth.

Let's assume we have: a browser cache, proxy cache and an origin server:

- The browser cache contains a stored stale resource with entity-tag "A".
- The proxy cache contains a stored stale resource with entity-tag "B". The proxy cache can act as a client, and as a server.

This can for example be the case if you're just starting to use a proxy cache. What will happen in this case?

- The browser will send a conditional request with If-None-Match: "A".
- The proxy cache receives the conditional request.
- The proxy cache will forward this request (according to the quote above). This is because the stored resource in proxy cache is stale.
- The origin server receives the request with the entity-tag "A".

Let's say, the resource on the origin server contains entity-tag "A". Now the server will respond with a 304 Not Modified response.

At this point, I don't understand things anymore, so maybe I misunderstood something before? The 304 response is okay for the browser cache, because it contains the same resource as on the origin server (same entity-tag). However, the proxy cache contains an older resource (with a different Etag). If the proxy cache would receive the 304 response (and would update its metadata), then the proxy cache makes a resource valid again while it's an old resource.

This is not desirable, so probably I made a mistake somewhere? How does it actually work? How I have to see this process?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [section 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.3) of the RFC7234 spec. Section 4.3.2 in particular says the following:

> When a cache decides to revalidate its own stored responses for a
> request that contains an If-None-Match list of entity-tags, the cache
> MAY combine the received list with a list of entity-tags from its own
> stored set of responses (fresh or stale) and send the union of the
> two lists as a replacement If-None-Match header field value in the
> forwarded request.  If a stored response contains only partial
> content, the cache MUST NOT include its entity-tag in the union
> unless the request is for a range that would be fully satisfied by
> that partial stored response.  If the response to the forwarded
> request is 304 (Not Modified) and has an ETag header field value with
> an entity-tag that is not in the client's list, the cache MUST
> generate a 200 (OK) response for the client by reusing its
> corresponding stored response, as updated by the 304 response
> metadata (Section 4.3.4).

So the proxy can send both entity tags (A and B) to the origin server for validation. If the resource representation hasn't changed, the origin server will send a `304` response. If the entity tag in that response is `B`, the proxy can freshen its stale, stored response and use it to send a `200 OK` response to the client. Upon receiving this new response, the browser can update its cache with it.

Now, in the scenario you have specified, the `304 NOT MODIFIED` response contains the entity tag `A` (can such a scenario even occur, given that you are accessing the resources through the proxy?). The spec doesn't seem to address this specific case explicitly, but I guess you can just forward the `304 NOT MODIFIED` response to the browser. Upon receiving it, the browser can freshen the stale response using its meta data.

Comment: If you're just starting to use a proxy cache, then this can easily be the case. The browser cache can contain a newer version of the resource (compared with proxy cache).
If both entity-tags will be forwarded to the origin server and one will match, then the origin server will respond with a 304 status code. Because the entity-tag doesn't match,
the proxy cache can decide to just forward the response. But that makes the proxy cache useless. 1/3

Comment: If only that user, uses the proxy cache for that specific URI, then the proxy
cache has no function for that URI. In my opinion it would be more logical to send the entity-tag "B" to the origin server only. Then the proxy cache will get a 200 OK response from the
origin server, and it can send a 304 response to browser cache. 2/3

Comment: And what in case of only Last-Modified? If you're just starting to use the proxy, and the Last-Modified date/time in browser cache is the same as on the origin server, and it's more 
recent then the one in proxy cache? A 304 response will not contain a Last-Modified field. So a cache will receive a 304 response ... how it has to decide to which resource 
these metadata belong? That's impossible. So what will happen with the situation if you're only using Last-Modified? There will be problems. That's why it's hard for me to believe it's
really like that. 3/3

Comment: And see: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234#section-4.3 (Validation): "to give the NEXT inbound server an opportunity to select a valid stored response". According to this, it has to be the NEXT server that selects a valid stored response. If the proxy cache (next server) will not store the response and will not have a valid stored response in the end, then your answer doesn't match the definition of validation. The proxy cache must make its stored response valid again. The origin server generates a response, but doesn't contain a stored response.

Comment: The keyword in the quoted section is `MAY`. It's completely up to the particular proxy cache implementation to decide whether to send the union of the etags or just the etags sent by the client.

Comment: I don't see any problem with Last-Modified. It serves the same purpose as an etag (although Last-Modified is a weak validator while etags may or may not be weak). In the absence of an etag, you can send `Last-Modified` header in a 304 response. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232#section-4.1

Comment: Again, I don't see how it contradicts the scenario given in the question. It doesn't say that by the end of the validation at the browser, all the intermediary caches should have freshened responses.

Comment: "MAY" refers to combining entity-tags, but what in case of not combining? Will the origin server receive enity-tag "A" or "B"? If it's "A", then you will have the same problems.
And Last-Modified is different then the Etag in case of a 304 response. See: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232#section-4.1 As a proxy cache, you can assume that a 304 response
contains a Etag (if enabled), but you can not assume that it will contain Last-Modified. That's the difference.

Comment: And you're saying that at the end of the validation, all intermediary caches should have freshened responses. That's only possible if the origin server will receive the entity-tag "B".
If the entity-tags will not combined (no MAY), which entity-tag will be sent to the origin server do you think, "A" or "B"? And from which part in the protocol you're drawing that conclusion?